# CA certificate authentication using libcurl

Tags: c++, ssl, g++, libcurl

I have a problem with getting a certificate to work with libcurl.

C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    // const char* szURL = "https://www.google.se/";
    const char* szURL = "https://api-sandbox.oanda.com/";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, szURL);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./ca.crt");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The file ca.crt is have placed in the same folder as my sample program, and the file looks like:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
/* A LOT OF CHARACTERS AND NUMBERS */
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

The contents of that file I retrieved by doing:

```
openssl s_client -connect api-sandbox.oanda.com:443 > logfile
```

I then copy-pasted the ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ..... ----END CERTIFICATE-----
part into a en empty file and saved it as ca.crt.

The program prints:

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

I'm using MinGW 64-bit (g++ compiler) on Windows 8.
What am I missing?

I have been able to make a request to https://www.google.se/ by using a ca-bundle which was generated by a VB-script which came with the libcurl-development pack. Apparently, it is a script which

> Script to fetch certdata.txt from Mozilla.org site and create a
> '* ca-bundle.crt for use with OpenSSL / libcurl / libcurl bindings

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I downloaded this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt

It appeared this file contained a certificate from Thawte Server CA.
When running the openssl command we could see:

```
i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
```

This hinted about Thawte. The code I posted above was indeed correct, it seems the certificate was not correct. Why that is I don't know (anyone with knowledge in then openssl tool: feel free to post an answer to that).